# Redefining proof environment so that it won't affect lists within the environment

Tags: lists, environments

As part of my topology course, we filled in a book/course notes on Overleaf. As such I did not write the front matter of the book (my only contribution to it was adding in the verbatim package for multiline comments). The professor defined a new proof environment as follows:

```
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{$\qedsymbol$}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \list{}
{\leftmargin=1.25mm\itemindent=20pt\linewidth=0.975\textwidth%
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
      \bfseries
  #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces}
}{%
  \popQED\endlist\@endpefalse
}
```

However this definition is causing issues within the book whenever someone uses a list within a proof. The first item is not labeled (I assume that's the \hskip\labelsep but I'm not sure) and the second item has a bolded label. Is there a way I can rewrite the proof environment so it was the same layout, but does not impact lists within proofs? I would prefer to not have to rewrite the proofs with lists.

EDIT: Things were getting clustered so I removed the image and code snippet.

This should run (worked on Overleaf and TeX Works).

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\setlist[enumerate]{label=(\arabic*)}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\square}% PLEASE NOTE: this is in the AMS symbols font.
\makeatletter

\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{$\qedsymbol$}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \list{}{\leftmargin=1.25mm\itemindent=20pt\linewidth=0.975\textwidth%
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \bfseries
   #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces}
}{%
  \popQED\endlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{proof} Stuff
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly is the code for the image? The code for the proof env looks a lot like the one from amsthm. I'm guessing that you are not using a list inside the proof env but write `\item` directly, which is wrong.

Comment: Didn't think to post that

Comment: Added the code to the main post.

Comment: That looks fairly normal, can you expand this to a fully compilable minimal example we can copy and test?

Comment: Took me a little bit to figure out what was needed, but I added something that runs.

I did notice that if the list is at the very start of the proof, there is no problem. So if you take out the "Stuff" that I put in, there are no  formatting issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your professor is much better of by just reusing the `amsthm` original and not using `\list` to define it. The tombstone placement is all wrong in this example

If all the processor want is boldface instead of italics then use

```
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        %\itshape
        \bfseries   
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
```

Alternatively make sure the `\list` definition ends before `\item` i.e.

```
\list{}{\leftmargin=1.25mm\itemindent=20pt\linewidth=0.975\textwidth}%
\item[\hskip\labelsep
      \bfseries
 #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
```

Then the list also works as expected. It is the `\item` inside the `\list` argument that is causing trouble